# Scaffolded Entity Framework DeletePersonalData not working onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor

I'm hoping someone can help me here. I scaffolded in the Entity Framework DeletePersonalData page to my project and changed some styling and layout, but I do not think I changed any of the default functionality.

However, when the **"Delete data and close my account"** button is clicked nothing happens. My other scaffolded pages are working fine and changing the DB when required.

Also if it helps, when I enter no password and click the button nothing happens. So the                 `if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, Input.Password))` is not working either.

Nothing at all is happening in the inspect tab of chrome dev tools when I click so the Post is not being triggered.

I did an add-migration and update-database just in case. It didn't help.

Using **.Net Core 3.0**

Any ideas?

**cshtml:**

```
                                <div class="col-lg-9 font-style-content">
                                <div class="form-group justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                    <br />
                                    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                                    @if (Model.RequirePassword)
                                    {
                                        <div class="form-group justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                            <label class="font-heading" asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                                            <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                                            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger button-title" type="submit">Delete data and close my account</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

**cshtml.cs:**

```
using MyApp.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using LocSourceNameReferenceLibrary;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage
{
    public class DeletePersonalDataModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<DeletePersonalDataModel> _logger;

public DeletePersonalDataModel(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<DeletePersonalDataModel> logger)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }

        public bool RequirePassword { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
        {
            public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }

            RequirePassword = await _userManager.HasPasswordAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }

        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }

            RequirePassword = await _userManager.HasPasswordAsync(user);
            if (RequirePassword)
            {
                if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, Input.Password))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Incorrect password.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            var result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred deleting user with ID '{userId}'.");
            }

            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

            _logger.LogInformation("User with ID '{UserId}' deleted themselves.", userId);

            return Redirect("~/");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the **form method="post"** tag in my cshtml file. oops!

```
<form id="delete-account-form" method="post">
```